# Services PATCH multiple target_id values for entity (node)

Tags: services

I'm trying to pass multiple nids to my node to match this structure:

```
[field_sac_testts] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [target_id] => 168
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [target_id] => 175
                            )

                    )

            )
```

I've tried this:

{"_links":{"type": {"href":"http://mywebsite.com/rest/type/node/subject"}},"type":[{"target_id":"subject"}],"field_sac_testts":[{"0": {"target_id":"702}},{"1": {"target_id":"729"}}]}

And a bunch of other combinations and I can't seem to get it to PATCH successfully. I keep getting a syntax error.

If anyone could help that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried this too: `code`{"_links":{"type": {"href":"http://mywebsite.com/rest/type/node/subject"}},"type":[{"target_id":"subject"}],"field_sac_testts":[{"target_id":"761"}],[{"target_id":"774"}]}

Answer (score 0):

OK. So figured it out. If you have an unlimited number of entry field for a entity type field (e.g. a node) on a content type you'll need to format the target_id with the nids like this for Drupal 8:

"field_sac_testts":[{"target_id":"830"},{"target_id":"837"}]